# How to change a class from a HTML element in parent blade template

Tags: php, laravel, templates, menu, laravel-blade

I'm not that experienced with Laravel, so I have created a project for myself to learn the Laravel framework better. I have started with a free HTML template and tried to turn that into a Blade template. I have the following:

**app.blade.php**

This contains the basic HTML structure and the JS en CSS. Besides that, it contains the following code:

```
<main class="page-content content-wrap">
    @include('layouts.topbar')

    @include('layouts.menu')

    @yield('content')
</main><!-- Page Content -->
```

**topbar.blade.php**

This contains the simple topbar that the template included, not that interesting for this question.

**menu.blade.php**

This contains all of the menu items I have. This file contains the whole menu-div and all of the menu items with ul and li. In this file, I can give a ul & li the class "active", so it shows that you're on page X. The standard ul (not active) is the class "droplink", when it's active, it's called "droplink active open".

**Views for the website itself**

In the views for the website I include the app.blade.php and I fill the content section in the view. Now my question is, how can I change that the correct page is showing active in the menu? My feeling says I can't define that in the menu.blade.php, but where can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name your routes `->name('homepage');`

And in your menu you can use this for exmaple:

```
  <li class="{{ isActiveRoute('dashboard') }}">
```

Which will return 'active if its active'

Use css to customize your `active` class

> Edit

Add the helper function in app/Helpers/Navigation.php

```
  function isActiveRoute($route, $output = 'active')
    {
        if (Route::currentRouteName() == $route) {
            return $output;
        }
    }
```

And in order to use it everywhere register it in your `AppServiceProvider.php`

```
public function register()
    {
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../Http/Helpers/Navigation.php';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried to apply this in my menu.blade.php, but I get an ErrorException: Call to undefined function isActiveRoute(). Do I have to create that function first somewhere?

Comment: Yes definitely. You need to create that function and than this will work

Comment: Thanks for your edit! I added the function and it works like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can check current route in **menu.blade.php**

If it matches with the current route than you can add active class.

```
<a class="{{ str_contains(request()->url(), '/some-page') ? 'active' : '' }}" href="/some-page">Some Page</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!

So, if I understand correctly, I have to check if the route matches the menu item for every menu item and then change the class to active?

Comment: Yes, you need to check every menu item

Comment: You can add condition for every menu. It will add active class based on route.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have chosen for a cleaner look with the isActiveRoute function as Onix said.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
@if(Route::getCurrentRoute()->uri() == '/') <li class="active"></li> @endif
```

It can be also used like this for example

```
<li class="@if(Route::getCurrentRoute()->uri() == '/')active @endif"></li>
```

For other routes to check just change the `/` to something like `about-us` or whatever you need.

---

This whill check for the current route. If the current route is `/` or root in this case it will add the li with class active. You can place this wherever you need it.

You can use this approach for each of your routes in `'layouts.menu'`

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have chosen for a cleaner look with the isActiveRoute function as Onix said.